# JUnit runs test several times

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I had a failing unit test and wondered why. I found out that the test is executed 400 times. Trying to figure out what causes the test to execute so many times, I reduced the code to the following:

```
package reproduce;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.experimental.results.PrintableResult.testResult;

public class FailingTest
{
    static int objCount = 0;

    public FailingTest()
    {
        objCount++;
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println(objCount);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
        testResult(FailingTest.class); // comment this to run only once
    }
}
```

In my tearDown() method, I'm trying to find out the result of the tests, because my cleanup operation could takes some minutes, so I only want to clean up in case of a failure, but not in case of succcess.

I found the use of `testResult()` in [code of the verifier rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules#verifier-rule) and thought it would be useful for me, but it won't be useful if my tests are run 400 times as often.

Is that a bug of the experimental PrintableResult, am I doing something wrong or is there another/easier way of achieving my intended result?

Comment: Nice minimal test-case.  However, on a side-note, I'm not entirely clear I understand the use-case here.  What kind of cleanup do you need to do that you can happily skip in some cases but not others?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: If the test was not successful, I need to reset a virtual machine to a snapshot, which takes 5 minutes. I'm misusing JUnit to implement system tests. The tearDown() method shall become part of a base class.

Comment: See https://github.com/pomkine/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/results/PrintableResult.java Inside testResult it seems that your test executed again so it is recursion call.

Comment: Could you implement your own listener? http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html

Comment: @  pomkine : that should be the answer.

Comment: @pomkine: Yeah, that should be the answer. Extending the `TestWatcher` rule and overriding `failed()` is much better than implementing an @After method and creating a superclass.

Comment: @Thomas yeah :) Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Junit PrintableResult source](https://github.com/pomkine/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/experimental/results/PrintableResult.java) Inside testResult it seems that your test executed again so it is recursion call. Some usefull info about getting test results can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_api.htm)